# Question about new inverter for solar power system

Tags: electrical, solar, inverter

I am new to this community so I hope this is the right place.

I am looking into buying a new inverter for my off grid cabin running from solar. I would like to purchase [THIS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00I0B2KJK) 3000w inverter. My question is... in the unlikely event that I run this at its full 3000w  capacity, what is the draw from my 12v battery bank in either amp hours or watt hrs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 3000 / 12 is 250A ignoring losses so a bit more in reality. So 1 hour is 250 amp hours

Comment: Is there a reason you're running the battery bank at 12V instead of at a higher voltage? Also, inverters aren't something I'd chintz out on if I were you...and where are you on this planet, for that matter?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'm running to battery bank on 12v because it's a 12-24v solar system. Also, if I reveal my super secret location, it kinda defeats the purpose of my off grid cabin. Lol. Lastly, is there a reason you think this inverter isn't good enough? It sounded like you thought it was a cheap option.

Comment: @SolarMike thank you. I thought it would be something like that. My dad and I were talking about it and I had said that(correct me if I'm wrong) 3000w worth if work on the ac side would require 3000w the DC side. Example 120v 10a pump is 1200 watts so we would need 12v 100a from the dc side. They both equal 1200w. If this is true then could you run that pump for 30 min on a 12v 50ah battery? Only considering numbers not reality and efficiency.

Comment: @BigCountry -- don't need or want GPS coordinates, but a country and perhaps some info about what rules your AHJ follows would be nice :)

Comment: Also, are you only interested in having 120V, or is having 240V as well something you'd be interested in in the future?

Comment: @BigCountry, 3000W on the output side requires more than 3000W on the input side .... there are conversion losses involved  ... if the inverter is 90% efficient, then you would need 3000W/90% = 3333W on the input side

Comment: @jsotola thanks. I figured there would be some extra elements involved like that.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'm in TN in the U.S. I don't plan on ever needing 240v. At most I'm only running a few led lights, and the periodical power needed for my low power pump. I would give specs for that but I'm thinking of changing that as well. This inverter looked nice for the soft starter already in it. I'm already using a much smaller inverter but I wanted to upgrade so I could smooth out those power surges and have a little extra capacity incase the kids want a movie night. Maybe even a small 1/2hp intex pool pump. That's probably in the far future though.

Comment: @Harper I know there are many things that run on 12v so I don't need a list of them. My current system runs this way. My biggest reason for incorporating 120v is a deep well pump that is strong enough for my usage. My current 12v one and other comparable affordable ones are just not enough.

Comment: @BigCountry Sorry, we're here to help, but I have little patience for people who present too little information to be helpful, then get sore when we guess.  Best of luck on your project.

Comment: @Harper my apologies if I came across as upset. I guess that's the nature of text. I was only saying that I don't need a list since I already have the things I need currently running 12v, are already operational. They will also remain that way in the new system. My question is about the inverter and I essentially was making sure we were calculating the wattage correctly for both ac and dc. I feel there is enough information in the original for it to be answered and it was. My last comment also was to assure you that we did in fact need the inverter due to the usage of the pump.

Comment: @BigCountry -- how many HP of well pump are you looking to run here?

Comment: Your battery capacity will need to be at least 2x the value you need or if you want. For 1 hour run time you will need a battery capacity of 500 ah, pulling a battery below 50% shortens it’s life even a deep cycle battery 80 % shortens the life with regular cycling. I understand the want for 12v but the losses and harmonics are much greater with 12v compared to 24v when creating 120v ac.

Comment: Sorry to have been grumpy earlier.  Let me see if I can put together a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there's a sizing issue here because I'd be surprised if a 3000W inverter could *start* a 3000W motor.

If you run the inverter at its nameplate capacity, your immediate 12 VDC current draw will be 300 amps or more.  Aside from inverter losses, you will have considerable voltage drop in whatever wires you are using to connect to the batteries, and indeed, through the batteries themselves.  The inverter will compensate for voltage sag by pulling more current.

So that means you'll need 300AH per hour.  5 AH per minute.

### Invert as soon as possible ... For the big loads

You'll want the inverter as close to the batteries as safety permits, with battery-battery and battery-inverter interconnects of heavy 2/0 or even 4/0 wire.  I've seen a solar project fail because they used (seemingly generous) #10 wire to carry 20A@12V eighty feet.

The goal is to cover distance at the highest voltage possible, because raising voltage both lowers current and lowers the importance of voltage drop. The benefit is (voltage/voltage) squared - e.g (120/12)^2 is 100x better to transmit as 120V than 12V, and (240/12)^2 400x better for 240V.

With 120V you must also watch voltage drop, but it becomes a factor over much longer distances in the 100-200' range (and don't forget the distance *down* the well, unless the motor is at the top; most are at the bottom).

Use a voltage drop calculator with your distance, voltage and continuous current draw (not startup surge).  Override the absurd 3% and allow 40% or so, merely to see how bad it will be at the minimum allowed wire size.  Anything more than about 6-8% needs remediation.

- You can recompute with a 6% value and see what it says for wire size.
- If it's recommending hundreds of dollars of wire, recompute for 240V.  If that number is much more favorable, then it's time to go 240V on the well pump (but do not increase horsepower!)

You don't need a 240V inverter. You can make 240V (at half the current) with 120V and a simple transformer.  The 120V side of the transformer looks like any other 120V load.  A motor of same horsepower will have the same current draw (from the 120V side). Transformers have a trivial power drop of 1-3%. They handle startup surge without worry (unlike inverters) so size for the motor's continuous draw.

### Deep cycling is a problem, though

As discussed, you'll need 300A+ from a 12V battery.  That's 5AH per minute or 300AH per hour.

Beware lead-acid, as they take damage from discharging, so their *practical, everyday* capacity is nowhere near their nameplate capacity.  Seriously. If you draw only 20-30% of a lead-acid's capacity and then recharge it, the battery will work for years.  If you start dipping it to 50%, you shorten its life to a few hundred such dips, and if you discharge 80% of its nameplate capacity, you'll greatly shorten its life to dozens of such cycles.

So a 300AH **lead-acid** battery would very quickly fail.  Best practice is a 4x oversize, so now you are talking about a 1200AH battery.

Lithium batteries do much better, and nickel batteries are almost impervious.  Apple and Tesla get phenomenal performance out of lithium batteries (this 7yo iPad is run down daily and still has nearly full range) by including 20-30% more battery *and not letting you use it*.  Once Tesla pushed a software patch to hurricane customers that let them use the *full* range of their battery. This gave them 100+ more miles!

### Make hay while the sun shines

If you have a location at a higher altitude than your house, you can put a storage tank there.  Water in the storage tank pressurizes your system and delivers water to the house.  The pump tops up this tank *when the sun is shining and the panel is at peak delivery*.

Faucet pressure is based on altitude difference, 1 PSI per 2 feet of altitude.

So for instance if the solar panels are producing 2000W of power, your 3000W load is only drawing 1000W from the battery, which has a big impact on sizing.

If the solar array is 3000W then the battery sizing issue pretty much goes away (least as far as the pump is concerned), you're only borrowing from the battery for startup surge.

As a bonus to this, you can spin down the inverter when you're not using the pump, so you don't have the parasitic "standby losses" of the inverter, which really beat you up because they're 24x7.

Also, this lets you do irrigation at sensible times rather than at the height of the day when the sun is shining.  The tank size is the limit; essentially you're storing "pumping energy" hydraulically rather than electrically. Tanks are cheaper than batteries.

Comment: I appreciate all this extra information! We actually currently have a tank up the hill for the exact reason you mention. So our system already covers that. The problem is that where the well is, it is very deep and in order to get it from the ground and up the hill is a tremendous job for the pump so it burned out. We started using a smaller compression tank and that seems to work well but we still need a stronger pump. For what we need, we have to go to a pump on 120v. The pump in particular I believe is about 800w. I never planned on getting a 3000w pump.

Comment: we wanted to get an inverter at least 3x the motor wattage due to how induction motors work with that heavy startup. If you're still wanting to know more, we are considering moving to a 24v system or possibly a 48v as suggested above. We are also trying to price batteries to create a robust enough bank that we should never get down below 80%. Hopefully this sounds good to you. I'm trying to piece everyone's info together and so far, that's where its leading us.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing many comments, I believe the best answer to my question is 250amp Hrs. when only considering the numbers provided.

3000w/12v = 250A

In order to maintain the 3000w output, you would need more on the input due to conversion loss. If the inverter is 90% efficient, then you would need 3000W/90% = 3333W on the input side.

Thank you Solar Mike for the original answer.
Thank you jsotola for the extra info that helped with a better final answer.
And thanks to the rest of you for helping and making me think of more questions! :)

Comment: 250A is insane, you would need wiring thicker than your arm. you have no need of such capacity, mentioning only about 0.5kw of load with your pump and lights and movies all running...

Comment: @dandavis I agree it is a lot. We don't plan on using that much either. My dad and I were just looking at a project we're working on and were writing out some hypotheticals. In order to ask the original question I just decided to use the numbers from a potential piece of equipment involved.

Comment: @dandavis a 4/0-4/0-4/0-2/0 SE cable is not exactly "thicker than one's arm" :P

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: heh, some exaggeration applies. I still think feeder-level current capacity is a mismatch for OP's cabin.

Comment: 4/0-4/0-4/0-2/0 Al would make acceptable DC feeder because you'd parallel blackgreen- redwhite+, presuming your current or distance is sensible.  If both current and distance are insensible, rethink.  If they **must** be insensible, then you're buying structural Al bar, and wrapping with tape.  Al not least to make the pieces handleable.  Copper is twice the weight!